# Help in understanding the ending of the book “The Alteration”

Tags: the-alteration

How did Hubert develop the diseases at just the wrong moment? Was this just a mere co-incidence or was it part of someone's plan?

Comment: It would have been better to edit the existing (closed) question and get it re-opened (and hopefully upvoted) than to post an entirely new question.

Comment: @Valorum I wasn't sure if the post could be salvaged since it had already received 2 downvotes

Comment: If you edit it into a good question, I can pretty much guarantee it'll end up in positive territory

Comment: @Valorum I had three specific questions with respect to the book's ending. I really couldn't find a way to put it in any way other than stating them in a straightforward manner. But perhaps that's not allowed. So, I'm asking a single question hoping it'll get a response

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting two (or three or twenty) questions about a property as long as they're all on-topic and you're reasonably sure that the answer to one won't answer another.

Comment: @Valorum That was exactly the case with my last question (IMO), but it was closed saying that only one question is allowed per post

Comment: Yes. You need to ask each individual question *as an individual question* but there's no limit on how many good individual questions you can ask, as long as you don't try to smoosh them all into a single question box.